# Column does not belong to data table in the foreach loop iteration

Tags: c#

Column does not belong to data table in the foreach loop iteration in C#.

I am inserting row by row records to a data table, however facing column does not belong to data table.

```
//Prepare Datatable and Add All Columns Here
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dc.ColumnName = "title";
            dc.ReadOnly = false;
            dc.Unique = true;
            dc.AutoIncrement = false;

            dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dc.ColumnName = "link";
            dc.ReadOnly = false;
            dc.Unique = true;
            dc.AutoIncrement = false;

            foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes)
            {
                XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
                string title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";

                rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
                string link = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";

                //Add new row and assign values to columns, no need to add columns again and again in loop which will throw exception
                row = dt.NewRow();
                //Map all the values in the columns
                row["title"] = title;
                row["link"] = link;


                //At the end just add that row in datatable
                dt.Rows.Add(row);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting each column, you need to call `dc = new DataColumn();` which you do for the first column but not the second. And after setting all the parameters of the column, you need to add it to the table `dt.Columns.Add(dc);`.

```
DataColumn dc;
dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "title";
dc.ReadOnly = false;
dc.Unique = true;
dc.AutoIncrement = false;
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "link";
dc.ReadOnly = false;
dc.Unique = true;
dc.AutoIncrement = false;
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Comment: thanks.. but where exactly you are advising me to do so.. in the above code snippets..

Comment: @goofyui - Here you go!